# Symfony2 - Entity Collection Choice Restriction

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, twig

I have the following setup:

```
Entity: Customer
Entity: Account
Entity: Message
```

Now imagine the following problem:

> The account 'Mark' is in charge of two customers, 'Ben' and 'Lili'.
>
> The account 'Tim' is in charge of two other customers, 'Tom' and 'Ronny'.
>
> The account 'Ben' now wants to send a message to his customers. In a form he can choose the customers he would like to send the message to. Those will be saved as an ArrayCollection in the Message entity (in relation with entity Customer).
>
> However, later on account 'Tim' can view this message and also send it to his customers the same way - by adding his customers to the list of recepients.
>
> Problem is: When 'Tim' adds his recepients, he should not see the recepients of 'Ben' as this is none of his concern.

Visual explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/q0nn62o5/

My solution so far:

I created a custom FormType called 'AccountCustomerType'. This FormType is an entity which includes the customers of one particular account as choices:

```
$builder
    ->add('customer', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Customer',
        'choices' => $this->customers,
    ));
```

This FormType is used in the main form as a collection:

```
$form->add('recepients', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AccountCustomerType($customers),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'delete_empty' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
));
```

Printing form...:

```
<div class="recepients" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.recepients.vars.prototype)|e }}">
    {% for customer in form.recepients %}
        <div>
            {{ form_widget(customer) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

One problem left:

> I can now choose from the customers that one account is in charge of. However, the recepients I am not in charge of are still shown as blank select fields. How can I hide these? I don't want to duplicate messages to seperate recepients as there are a couple more features connected to this.

Comment: How about injecting the current user instance (that would be *Mark* or *Tim* for example) to your `AccountCustomerType` instead of passing `$customers` as argument, and then replace property `choices` with `query_builder` and pull only these recipients that are connected to the current user that you injected?

Comment: Whether I inject the customers via property 'choices' or fetch them via 'query_builder' doesn't matter - that just selects the options in the drop down list. You have to differentiate between options in the choice-drop-down-list and chosen recipients in the collection. In this case I need to restrict the collection, not the choice-field. - Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe this example makes it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/q0nn62o5/

Comment: I still find it hard to believe that this cannot be achieved with query alone. All you have to do is pull every possible recipient that is not currently associated with another user account. Whether you pull them with query, or apply `->filter()` callback to `ArrayCollection` it should work theoretically. Can you show how you create your `$customers` variable?

Comment: $customers just sets the <option> tags in the <select>. That works perfectly fine. The drop-down-list in the select-field works fine. The recipients shown in the collection are not. There are empty fields printed because there is a recipient but the recipient not in the select-field available. It's a collection of recipients displayed with entity-field-types. The entity-field-types work fine, the collection doesn't. The problem is that I can't filter the shown recipients in the Message entity.

Comment: Can I filter the ArrayCollection in the Message entity and then somehow set the data for the collection?

Comment: You can try adding custom method that applies `->filter()` callback to your Collection and adds only the required values/choices to an empty array which you return at the end of your method. That of course would work well if you use the option `property` on `entity` type, but you already said that your choice list is populated just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a collection in a form by restricting the query results.

E.g. something like:

```
$accountData = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()->select('a, c')
    ->from('YourAccountBundle:Account', 'a')
    ->join('a.customers', 'c') // assuming there is a relationship like this
    ->where('a = :yourAccountManager')
    ->setParameter('yourAccountManager', $accountEntity) 
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Then use $accountData in your parent form.

This will restrict the Customer entities shown in the form to only the ones linked to $accountEntity.

Note this needs to be the first fetch of this relation in your page load, if you lazy load it with doctrine then it'll return all Customer entities regardless of filtering.

Comment: Just also noting that the above is not exactly what you're after in terms of relationships but the principle is the same, you'd join the Message, Account and Recipient entities restricting Recipients to the Chosen Account only .

Comment: I was able to solve it myself yesterday but that's pretty much it. I used the 'mapped' attribute of the collection field to avoid it being mapped to the entity. Instead the field is now getting validated seperately and the entity is getting updated manually.